# $3\cdot \cos ^2\left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=1$. Solving for $x$ without the solution being "entirely graphical or numerical"

Tags: trigonometry

It was on a high school test paper for a relative. He couldn't solve it.

Just trying to solve this equation:
$$3\cdot \cos ^2\left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=1$$
at the end, it says "Entirely graphical or numerical solutions are not acceptable." I would've just fed it into a calculator to get the answer. If it were $$2\cdot \cos ^2\left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=1$$, I could've solved it but I can't find an algebraic solution to this one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should check out our section about LaTeX and MathJax. You should also include your solution/try on your question.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude I definitely would check it out. Sorry, I was in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

I do really want to comment but since I cannot comment (needs 50 reputation to comment), hence I solve here. Hope this will helps you. Thank you. I do solve this in the range of 0 to 360 degree.

$$3\cdot \cos ^2\left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=1$$
$$\cos ^2\left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\cos ^2\left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$\cos \left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\:,\:\cos \left(2x+10^{\circ \:}\right)=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$ $$
$$\cos \left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\:$$
$$2x+10^{\circ \:}=\cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right),360^{\circ }-\cos \:^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$
$$2x+10^{\circ \:}=40.55^{\circ \:},360^{\circ }-40.55^{\circ \:\:}$$
$$2x+10^{\circ \:}=40.55^{\circ \:},319.45^{\circ }$$
$$2x=30.55^{\circ \:},309.45^{\circ }$$
$$x=15.275^{\circ \:},154.725^{\circ }$$

$$ $$
$$\cos \left(2x+10^{\circ }\right)=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\:$$
$$2x+10^{\circ \:}=180^{\circ }-\cos \:^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right),180^{\circ }+\cos \:^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$
$$2x+10^{\circ \:}=180^{\circ }-40.55^{\circ \:\:},180^{\circ }+40.55^{\circ \:\:}$$
$$2x+10^{\circ \:}=139.45^{\circ \:},220.55^{\circ }$$
$$2x=129.45^{\circ \:},210.55^{\circ }$$
$$x=64.725^{\circ \:},105.275^{\circ }$$

$$ $$
$$x=15.275^{\circ \:},64.725^{\circ \:},105.275^{\circ },154.725^{\circ }$$

Comment: I don't think that's it. That's a very numerical way to go about it and frankly the first thing I would do. They want an algebraic solution. I am half thinking maybe the question itself is not correct.

Comment: @VipulRajan you could always just draw a graph showing how lengths are never negative and that will make it not entirely numerical ;)

Answer (score 0):

$$3\cos^2(2x+10°)=1 \Leftrightarrow 2\cos^2(2x+10°)-1=-\frac{1}{3} \Leftrightarrow\\
\cos(4x+20°)=-\frac{1}{3}\Leftrightarrow\cos(4x+200°)=\frac{1}{3}\Leftrightarrow\\ 4x+200°=\pm\arccos\frac{1}{3}+360°\cdot k, k\in \mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow\\x+50°=\pm\frac{1}{4}\arccos\frac{1}{3}+90°\cdot k,k\in\mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow\\
x=\pm\frac{1}{4}\arccos\frac{1}{3}-50°+90°\cdot k,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

I have other numerical result: for $x\in [0°;90°)$ numerical values of $x$  are 22.368°, 57.632°. All other values of $x$ can be obtained by adding or subtracting $90°\cdot n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.